# Is eAccelerator still relevant?

Tags: php, linux, apache, nginx, eaccelerator

It have been a very long time since I last saw anyone use or talk about [eAccelerator](http://eaccelerator.net/), so I wonder if memcached and redis have made it obsolete?

Comment: Your "question" is too broad and not really a question. More so a statement. Please supply code if you've run into trouble using this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP 5.5+ [ships with the opcache extension, formerly Zend Optimiser+, by default](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php), thereby obsoleting solutions like eAccelerator which do the same thing.

Memcached and Redis solve entirely different problems (data persistence), not code execution speed.

Comment: Minor correction: Memcached doesn't offer any data persistence capabilities - it is a pure caching solution.

Comment: @ItamarHaber in what way is a cache not a data persistence solution by definition? I never specified the type or duration of the persistence  :)  If it stores data for later use, it's providing persistence to that data.

Comment: I see what you mean - language tends to be fuzzy. I apologize and will make amends by up voting profusely :)